# System.err.println shows no output

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS 3.4 and working on a web application based on Grails framework.

When i try to use `System.err.println` in groovy classes it does not print anything on standard eclipse console(STS  console).

Actually there are times when in  print things but that is like 1 in 10, I couldn't understand this random behavior.

I am using some library that uses `System.err.println` for debugging purposes but i could not get any debugging info. All i need to know is where and how to get `System.err.println` output?

Please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: check you IDE settings if `err` is mapped to a disk log file.

Comment: IDE have default settings, I double checked it's not mapped anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

If it is a random behaviour, it may be not-`flush`-ed buffered stream. Especially, that can happen when output comes from different thread.

As a solution,  you can hook in into `System.err` dispatching (it's a stream, that you can set from outside), and overload functions, to get desired output anywhere you want. Or simply force `flush` it. But be careful, as it may lead to performance problems.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using logging instead for more standard and  configurable output. This should help you to set it up: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Logging

Comment: Link-only answers aren't best suited to stackoverflow. Mind adding an excerpt from the page you are referencing?

Comment: I clearly stated I am using some library that uses System.err.How can i modify it? Please understand question completely before putting an answer